# MessageHandler not able to catch commands

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

we would like to monitor users who send commands to the bot,
but when the bot is started,
the messagehandler is able to catch messages and report that a private chat is started, but it seems that it can't catch any of the three pre-defined commands(which are working fine).

this is confusing.

below is the main function block.

thanks in advance.

```
def main() -> None:
    """Start the bot."""
    # Create the Application and pass it your bot's token.
    application = Application.builder().token("token").build()

    # Command handlers
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler('help', help_command))
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler('show_chats', show_chats))

    # Handle members joining/leaving chats.
    application.add_handler(ChatMemberHandler(greet_chat_members, ChatMemberHandler.CHAT_MEMBER))

    # Keep track of which chats the bot is in
    application.add_handler(ChatMemberHandler(track_chats, ChatMemberHandler.MY_CHAT_MEMBER))

    # Interpret any other command or text message as a start of a private chat.
    # This will record the user as being in a private chat with bot.
    application.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.ALL, start_private_chat))

    # Run the bot until the user presses Ctrl-C
    # We pass 'allowed_updates' handle *all* updates including `chat_member` updates
    # To reset this, simply pass `allowed_updates=[]`
    application.run_polling(allowed_updates=Update.ALL_TYPES)
```

and if i put the command handlers behind the messagehandler, they simply no longer work.

Comment: You leaked your bot token, please revoke it immediately.

Comment: do you need only non-command text messages to be passed to the `start_private_chat` function?

Comment: @Obaskly Nah, i would like all messages incl. texts or commands be passed to the start_private_chat funciton

Comment: what library are you using

Comment: I mean the function can now interpret any command other than 'start','help' and 'show_chats' or text message as a start of a private chat.
 however i dont want it to exclude those 3 commands.

Comment: @Obaskly these are my imports : import logging, os,re
from typing import Optional, Tuple
from telegram import __version__ as TG_VER
from telegram import ForceReply

Comment: basically i just coppied the imports from https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/chatmemberbot.py

Comment: This question has been asked and answered at https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/discussions/3649.